# cannot format bad hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, format, smart

I think I have a problem with my hard drive.

I tried to boot the system, and it was taking a long time. After a while it said that the drive was not bootable.

I tried running check disk, but it was unable to complete.

I then tried to remove it from the laptop to see if I can recover the files, but the drive does not appear to be formatted. When I tried to format the drive, I received a message that said that the formatting was not successful.

A S.M.A.R.T test returned a read failure.

The annoying thing is that when I try to format just a part of the drive, it works fine.

**EDIT** : Here is the log file output:

> 184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   001   001   001    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 1927

What does this mean?

**EDIT 2:** The machine that I have the drive plugged into is running windows 7 sp1, the driver is connected via usb (sata to usb) and the model of the hard driver is MK1652GSX and the model of laptop is Presario CQ60.

-----The full output of smartctl-----

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [i686-w64-mingw32-win7(64)-sp1] (sf-win32-5.41-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..52GSX
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK1652GSX
Serial Number:    Z8OGFLOVS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 176f05fb8
Firmware Version: LV011C
User Capacity:    160.041.885.696 bytes [160 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Thu Feb 09 21:03:59 2012 GTB
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  57) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0033) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   099   099   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1082
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5383
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   037   037   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1292
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       3949
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   207   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5085
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   001   001   001    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 1927
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1927
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   074   031   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 26 (Min/Max 21/27)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       106
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24969597
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       63745
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 13/69)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       257
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       148
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       3023
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       328
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2536 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2536 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3948 hours (164 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 00 d0 8c 41  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x018cd000 = 26005504

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 00 d0 8c 40 00      00:09:32.132  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 80 80 ac 8a 40 00      00:09:32.130  READ DMA EXT
  35 03 80 80 ac 8a 40 00      00:09:32.127  WRITE DMA EXT
  25 03 80 00 ac 8a 40 00      00:09:32.125  READ DMA EXT
  35 03 80 00 ac 8a 40 00      00:09:32.123  WRITE DMA EXT

Error 2535 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3948 hours (164 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 06 12 08 60 40  Error: UNC 6 sectors at LBA = 0x00600812 = 6293522

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 10 08 60 40 00      00:01:21.041  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 60 09 00 40 00      00:01:21.040  READ DMA EXT
  35 03 08 60 09 00 40 00      00:01:21.040  WRITE DMA EXT
  25 03 08 60 09 00 40 00      00:01:21.039  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 08 08 60 40 00      00:01:21.038  READ DMA EXT

Error 2534 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3948 hours (164 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 0a 05 08 60 60  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00600805 = 6293509

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:34.113  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:34.113  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:13:34.079  [RESERVED]
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:28.247  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:28.247  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 2533 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3948 hours (164 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 0a 03 08 60 60  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00600803 = 6293507

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:28.247  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:28.247  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:13:28.223  [RESERVED]
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:23.677  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:23.676  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

Error 2532 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3948 hours (164 days + 12 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 0a 03 08 60 60  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00600803 = 6293507

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:23.677  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:23.676  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ff      00:13:23.656  [RESERVED]
  60 08 08 00 08 60 40 00      00:13:18.232  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:18.232  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      3949         163251
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      3947         6293501
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      3946         6293501

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: More info on the hardware and exact Windows OS would help

Comment: the machine that i have plugin the toshiba hard drive is running windows 7 sp1 , the driver is connected via usb (sata to usb) the model of the hard driver is MK1652GSX and the model of laptop that i remove the driver is Presario CQ60. (service tag: CQ60-220EV) . thanks in advice!

Comment: Replace the hard drive, copy over any data you want and done.  Clonezilla to copy the whole drive at once, but with bad sectors it will take longer, maybe a lot longer.

Answer (score 3):

The drive has bad sectors and you are hitting them when you try to format.

Run the diagnostics offered by the drive's manufacturer, and if it can't 'fix' it the drive needs to be replaced.

Comment: it is a tosiba driver any idea where to find the manufacturer diagnostics ? i search in the website but i did find it

Comment: sorry i find the diagnost tool but i cannot select hardriver is unclickable ! ( http://storage.toshiba.com/storage-services-support/warranty-support/software-utilities )

Comment: @jkarr Then perhaps it's time to put a call into Toshiba?

Answer (score 0):

If the drive works on the laptop, but the volume shows as raw on another machine, it might be encrypted (truecrypt, etc). Is this a laptop which has been provided by a university or other large organization?

If it is encrypted, you will need the proper driver(s), software, and password to mount the volume on another machine

Answer (score 0):

It seems your drive might have some bad sectors. This often happens to old drives, as the read/write head and magnetic components wear out. It may be possible to repair those sectors, or disable them, as some hard drives come with software that allows them to be diagnosed and repaired, or the manufacturer might provide these tools on their website.

Do some research for your specific drive, and see what happens.

If all else fails, you probably need a new hard drive.